# How to bind onto Future cancellation?

Tags: java, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

I'm using classical `ScheduledExecutorService` interface and need to make sure that if task is not going to be invoked at all, my code will be notified via callback about that (speaking strictly, i need to cancel related `CompletableFuture` as soon as it is known task won't be run). How can i achieve that?

Comment: You can wrap the Future with your own object which will call your callback when cancel is called.

Comment: @PeterLawrey i'm sorry, i'm not very good at english these days. I'm looking for a way to correctly handle executor shutdowns and other interruptions, while question is obviously looking as if i was going to call `.cancel()` myself. I'll edit question in a second.

Comment: In that case you would need to wrap the ExecutorService and trace which Futures it creates so they can be notified when the ExecutorService is shutdown.